# XSLT Change element order

Tags: xslt

Say I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="http://someorg.org">
    <name>
    <use value="usual"/>
    <family value="family"/>
    <given value="given"/>
    <suffix value="MSc"/>
  </name>
</Test>
```

and I would like to change the order by for example having given before family so that we have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="http://someorg.org">
    <name>
    <use value="usual"/>
    <given value="given"/>
    <family value="family"/>    
    <suffix value="MSc"/>
  </name>
</Test>
```

I tried using xsl:paply.template as below but the problem is that since apply-templates applies templates to all child nodes, it would also output nodes whose order has being changed again and I do not know how I can prevent it from applying templates to nodes whose order has already being changed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://someorg.org"
xmlns="http://someorg.org"
exclude-result-prefixes="f xsl">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "f:name">
    <xsl:apply-templates select = "f:given"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select = "f:family"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>          
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the order you need to have the `apply-templates` in the order you want, i.e.

```
<xsl:template match = "f:name">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="f:use"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="f:given"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="f:family"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="f:suffix"/>
  </xsl:copy>          
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 2.0 it is easier to write

```
<xsl:template match = "f:name">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="f:use, f:given, f:family, f:suffix"/>
  </xsl:copy>          
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. So, I have to apply to each and every element template in the order that I want? Is there not a way to tell apply templates to only order say first two elements and then the rest appear as they are without any ordering? In my case for this example I only have a few templates but let us say one has dozens of elements and wants only positions of first and second element to be interchanged and rest appear as they are, so, even in this case one will have to write apply-templates dozens of time for each and every element?

Comment: You can replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="f:family"/><xsl:apply-templates select="f:suffix"/>` by `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::f:use | self::f:given)]"/>` which would then process all child element that are not `use` or `given`. In XSLT 2.0 you can use `except` e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="f:use, f:given, * except (f:use, f:given)"/>`

Comment: @Enigma, Imagine that you have 100 different element names and you want to order 50 of these? No matter what, you will have to write very long one or more `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction(s). Also, you will have to modify this already difficult to read code, every time a new ordering is required. A better, more generic solution is possible -- read my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a generic and short, complete XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="http://someorg.org">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOrdered" select="'|use|given|family|suffix|'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before($vOrdered, concat('|',name(),'|'))"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Test xmlns="http://someorg.org">
    <name>
        <use value="usual"/>
        <family value="family"/>
        <given value="given"/>
        <suffix value="MSc"/>
    </name>
</Test>
```

**the wanted, correct result, is produced**:

```
<Test xmlns="http://someorg.org">
   <name>
      <use value="usual"/>
      <given value="given"/>
      <family value="family"/>
      <suffix value="MSc"/>
   </name>
</Test>
```

**Do Note**:

1. Only a single `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction is used and the code of the templates will not be changed if we want to specify new order of the children of the `f:name` element.
2. The ordering of elements can be specified in a separate XML document that can be dynamically obtained using a standard function, such as `document()` into the current XSLT stylesheet and used as an independent "configuration file". Then the transformation will never have to be modified when new ordering is wanted -- only the config file needs to be modified.

Comment: Brilliant solution, just what I was looking for. If one would want to additionally preserve any existing attributes on `name`, how could this be achieved? Just change `select="*"` into `select="*|@*"`in the inner `xsl:apply-templates` element?

Comment: Answering myself here: one just needs to add a second `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` just before the `<xsl:apply-templates select="*">`, inside the `xsl:copy` element.

Comment: @Markus, Yes, and this is what I would do -- clear and short.