# XSLT to put one particular XML element before all others

Tags: xslt-1.0

XSLT 1.0 solution required. My question is similar to [XSLT Change element order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37442799/1016065) and I'll take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474855/1016065) if I have to, but I hope I can do something like 'put this_element first, and retain the original order of all the rest of them'. The input is something like this, where `...` can be any set of simple elements or text nodes, but no processing instructions nor comments. See below also.

```
<someXML>  
  <recordList>  
    <record priref="1" created="2009-06-04T16:54:35" modification="2014-12-16T14:56:51" selected="False">  
      ...
      <collection_type>3D</collection_type>  
      ...  
      <object_category>headgear</object_category>  
      <object_name>hat</object_name>  
      <object_number>060998</object_number>  
      ...  
    </record>  
    <record priref="3" created="2009-06-04T11:54:35" modification="2020-08-05T18:24:33" selected="False">  
      ...
      <collection_type>3D</collection_type>  
      <description>a very elaborate coat</description>  
      <object_category>clothing</object_category>  
      <object_name>coat</object_name>  
      <object_number>060998</object_number>  
    </record>
  </recordList>
</someXML>
```

This would be the desired output.

```
<someXML>  
  <recordList>  
    <record priref="1" created="2009-06-04T16:54:35" modification="2014-12-16T14:56:51" selected="False">  
      <object_category>clothing</object_category>  
      ...
      <collection_type>3D</collection_type>  
      ...  
      <object_name>hat</object_name>  
      <object_number>060998</object_number>  
      ...  
    </record>  
    <record priref="3" created="2009-06-04T11:54:35" modification="2020-08-05T18:24:33" selected="False">   
      <object_category>clothing</object_category>  
      ...
      <collection_type>3D</collection_type>  
      <description>a very elaborate coat</description>  
      <object_name>coat</object_name>  
      <object_number>060998</object_number>  
    </record>
  </recordList>
</someXML>
```

It's probably OK if `object_category` is put first, and then occurs again later on in the record, i.e. in the tags in their original order.

I'll add some background. There's this API producing about 900.000 XML records with different tags (element names) in alphabetical order, per record. There are about 170 different element names (that's why I don't want to have to list them all individually, unless there's no other way). The XML is ingested into this graph database. That takes time, but it could be sped up if we see the `object_category` as the first element in the record.

**Edit**: We can configure the API, but not the C# code behind the API. We step through the database, step by step ingesting chunks of ~100 records. If we specify nothing else, we get the XML as exemplified above. We can also specify an XSL sheet to transform the XML. That's what we want to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is ambiguous, because we don't know what all those `...` placeholders stand for. I suppose this should work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="object_category"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::object_category)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```